# Module javafx.base not found even though my path is correct

Tags: java, javafx

I know this looks like a repeat question but I have already tried looking all over the web and nothing seems to help. I am new to JavaFX and already have it installed yet I have the `Module javafx.base not found` error. These are my VM options `--module-path "C:\Users\Nguyen PC\Desktop/lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`
Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont have enough reputation for a comment: check your path, you have both backslash and forward slash in it. Also mind, to go into \javafx-sdk-*\lib

Comment: The reason must be a wrong lib directory, make sure you have downloaded the right one.

Answer (score 0):

VM options for windows

Modular:

--module-path path\to\Javafx\lib;mods\production

Non-modular:

--module-path "\path\to\Javafx\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

Comment: What does it mean by modular and non modular